# Ember.js - Different serializers for the same model (backend rails plus websocket updates)

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I want to initialize my market model by loading from my rails backend. I also have a websocket connection that provides realtime data to keep the model updated.

How do I serialize the data from the websocket without it also serializing the initialization request from the rails API? The serializer is attached to the model so I don't know how it can be separated.

The other problem is the websocket updates aren't going to have a primary key to update with pushPayload(). The market name (as in USDCAD below) will be unique though. How do I handle this?

**Websocket update example:**

```
{
  "platform": "trader-platform",
  "updateType": "summaryUpdate",
  "USDCAD": {
    "high": 234,
    "low": 143,
    "last": 200
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the market name can't be the primary key because a different platform may also have the same market name. I guess that means looking up each id before updating.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you must find the right record in order to get the ID. Without
  ID there is no way you can push data into store.
- Second, assign the ID into your payload.
- Then, if the paylod needs to be serialized use
  store.pushPayload(modelName, payload), else format your payload to a
  JSONApi doc and use store.push(jsonapidoc).